# Why is my Arrays.sort method returning an error?

Tags: java, sorting

I'm confused about how to use Arrays.sort in Java.

In my Java code, I'm  trying to sort the top 10 files in my directory, and so I'm going to use [Arrays.sort method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29).

First I create the array to hold the file lengths:

```
int[] sortedArray =  new int[11];
```

later on in my code, after I load numbers into sortedArray , I do this..

```
Arrays.sort(sortedArray);
```

but for some reason, it doesn't like that  .  I get this error:

```
TopTen.java:46: error: <identifier> expected
        Arrays.sort(sortedArray);
```

Here is the rest of my code

```
File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\Code\\Desktop\\Work\\Oracle_Training\\Java_training\\Java_Challenge_Disk_10_files");

for(File child : dir.listFiles()){
    System.out.print(child.getName() + " " + child.length() + " , ");   
    //puting into sortedArrya
    for (int i = 0; i<11; i++){ 
        sortedArray[i] = (int)child.length();
        continue;
    }
}

int[] array = new int[10];

Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

}

Arrays.sort(sortedArray);
```

Am i using `Arrays.sort` correctlY? thank you

Comment: It needs more context. Can you post a very short program showing the problem? One guess is that you are trying to do the sort outside any method, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Also, googling for "error: <identifier> expected" gets a ton of results.

Comment: You need to include valid, complete code to reproduce your problem, otherwise this question is unanswerable. Voting to close for now.

Comment: Near as I can tell there's nothing wrong with then code you posted: http://ideone.com/mnGBXG

Comment: You really need to indent your code better. I'm guessing you have an unnecessary `}` somewhere. (Like the one right before `Arrays.sort(sortedArray)` which might be closing the method unintendedly.)

Comment: @millimoose - true , & Thanks, I will work on that

Comment: What method is this in?

Comment: The safest way to sort out indentation is to use an editor that can automatically indent. That way, you can be sure the indentation matches what the code says, not what you meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `Arrays.sort()` correctly, but you forgot an opening brace after the start of the second `for` loop. In other words, change the last for loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

To prevent this from happening again, you can get into the habit of adding the braces and not taking them out *even if there is only one statement in the `for` loop*.

Comment: Oh my I will need to tattoo this lesson. I must always brace a For-loop .  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I think it's the **opposite**: there is an unnecessary closing bracket.  Why would one want to print array while it's being populated?

Comment: @PM77-1 - Well that's good point also